# How to check service running or not using batch script

Tags: batch-file, iis

I want to stop list of services and then after deployment start that services, But the Problem is getting while stopping the first service , if its already stopped then its not goes to stop another services.
Below is my sample code snippet

```
@ECHO OFF
set _serviceName1=dmwappushservice
set _serviceName2=DOORS DB Server 9.6
set _serviceName3=DusmSvc
sc query %_serviceName1% | findstr /i running| if "%errorlevel%"=="0" (net 
stop "%_serviceName1%") 
sc query %_serviceName2% | findstr /i running| if "%errorlevel%"=="0" (net 
stop "%_serviceName2%")
sc query %_serviceName3% | findstr /i running| if "%errorlevel%"=="0" (net 
stop "%_serviceName3%")
Pause
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: the `|` after running is piping the result into a new cmd session. instead try `sc query %_serviceName1% | find /i "running" && sc stop %_serviceName1%` or change `sc stop…` to `net stop…` first one doesn't wait the service to stop, second one does.

Comment: Also be careful of spaces in variable names, use best practice of `set "variable=string value"` and refer to your variables enclosed in double quotes, e.g. `"%variable%"` or `"!variable!"`.

Comment: `%errorlevel%` is expanded by current value of environment variable `ERRORLEVEL` __before__ the command `sc` is executed at all. Remove `@ECHO OFF` from batch file and run the batch file from within a command prompt window and you see the command line really executed. Use `if not errorlevel 1 net stop "%_serviceName1%"` instead of `if "%errorlevel%"=="0" (sc stop "%_serviceName1%")`. But better would be `%SystemRoot%\System32\sc.exe query "%_serviceName1%" | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /C:running >nul && %SystemRoot%\System32\sc.exe stop "%_serviceName1%" >nul`.